# Using php code inside jQuery script - wp_localize_script() not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use Bootstrap pop-over on an element inside wordpress loop. I have a javascript function that should ideally pull the title of the post, store it in a variable and return the variable... but, php block is stored as a sting. I've seen many threads here and elsewhere where the solution is to put the php block inside the `<?php ?>` but that just doesn't work here.

The popover displays: `<?php echo the_title(); ?>`

Is my script executed too early?

My code in .js file which is enqued with wp_enque_script():

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  
share = function() {
    var title = "<?php echo the_title(); ?>";
    return title;
}

$('.share').popover({
    content: share(),
    placement: 'bottom'
    });
});
```

**EDIT**

I used `wp_localize_script()` as suggested in one of the answers, but the variables return `null`

**functins.php**

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array(), '', true );

wp_localize_script('scripts', 'script_vars', array(
        'title' => the_title(),
        'url' => the_permalink()
        )
    );
```

**scripts.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){  

share = function() {
    var title = script_vars.title;

    return title;
}

$('.share').popover({
        content: share(),
        placement: 'bottom'
        });
});
```

Aditionally, `the_title()` and `the_permalink()` are echoed after the `<body>` tag on each page

Comment: Is this code in a .php file or a .js file?

Comment: Where is this script located?

Comment: code is in .js file which is enqued with `wp_enque_script()`

Comment: Instead of having this jQuery code in a separate .js file you may use this inline in a PHP file and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code, which seem to be common small mistakes with people new to WordPress dev.  Lets get it sorted.

1. Localize script is the right way to do this.
2. you need to know what values are available outside the loop, and how to get the title and permalink when you're not in the loop.
3. there are a few small issues with how you're enqueue'ing your script.

We're going to use a couple specific functions

- `get_the_title( $ID );` which will require the post ID outside of the loop and returns it for use in PHP rather than echo'ing it out.[link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title)
- `get_peramlink( $ID )` which also works outside the loop, and returns the permalink for use in PHP. [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink)
- we'll adjust the arguments you're passing to enqueue scripts, specifically the `array()` should be `array('jquery')` to show its dependancy on jQuery, which you're using in your script, we'll enqueue jquery as well, and also employ `wp_register_script`.

In your **functions.php** file

```
     function do_scripts()
     {  
         /* Get the ID of the current post */
         global $post;
         $ID = $post->ID;

         /* register the script */
         wp_register_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), false, true );
         $script_vars = array(
             'title'    => get_the_title( $ID ),
             'url'      => get_permalink( $ID )
         );

         /* actually enqueue jquery (that ships with WP) and your custom script */
         wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
         wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );

         /* Localize the vairables */
         wp_localize_script('custom', 'script_vars', $script_vars);

    }

     /* If we're not in the admin section call our function on the wp_enqueue_scripts hook  */
     if ( !is_admin() ) add_action( "wp_enqueue_scripts", "do_scripts", 10 );
```

This will work by creating a global javascript object and outputting it before your script is included.

In your **scripts.js** file you'll have access to this object.

```
 script_vars.title // will return the title
 script_vars.url // will return the permalink
```

Answer (score 2):

.js files are not processed by the php engine, so php tags won't be interpreted.

You could do something like this..

In your php file:

```
window.postTitle = "<?php echo the_title(); ?>";
```

In your js file:

```
$('.share').popover({
    content: window.postTitle,
    placement: 'bottom'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it that way because the Javascript isn't processed by PHP. It's just sent to the browser like a text file.

What you *can* do, though, is use [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to pass the title to your script. This function was originally written for internationalization/localization, but it's widely used in plugins & themes for passing values between PHP & Javascript.

Comment: actually this doesn't work, please see edited question. thanks!

Comment: @BojanaŠekeljić Swap the 2 script references round ;)

Comment: @Archer not sure I understand?

Comment: Ignore that last comment - you're running code in a `document.ready` handler, so it's not relevant.  Find the script created by `wp_localize_script` and make sure that the correct values are there.

Comment: You can't use the_title() outside [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). Use [wp_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_title) instead.

Comment: And for getting the current URL, either use [Konstantin's method](http://kovshenin.com/2012/current-url-in-wordpress/) or just grab `window.location.href` in your Javascript.

Comment: @DaveRoss tried with wp_title(), again empty, and since I added `wp_localize_script()` value of both declared variables, title and permalink, are displayed below the `<body>` tag, I've added edits to the question about these, did I use the localize wrong?

Comment: @DaveRoss I don't need the current url, I need the url of the post in the loop, `.share` element to which `.popover()` is bind is inside the loop